# how to terminate a shell when sub shell command fails?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to terminate a shell when a sub-shell command fails.

eg:

```
check(){
  if [ $1 -eq $1 2> /dev/null ]; then
      echo "returning 0"
      return 0
  else
      echo "returning 1"
      return 1
  fi
}

if [ "($check $1)" == 1 ]; then
    echo "Error: with proper message"
    exit
fi

if [ "$1" -le 1000 ] || [ "$2" -ge 10000 ]; then
    echo "Error:"
    exit 
fi
```

Here i am passing a string and first if condition fails and second if condition executes with the error in command line "integer expression expected". 
I am aware that () sub shell command fails but the shell is not terminating. How to exit from the shell when a sub-shell command fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test the exit status of the function.  The following:

```
if [ "($check $1)" == 1 ]; then
```

would probably result in an error.  Even if you said:

```
if [ "$(check $1)" == 1 ]; then
```

that would not compare the *exit status*, i.e. the *return value* of the function.  It would instead compare the *output* of the function with `1`.

You'd need to invoke your function by saying:

```
check $1
```

and then check the exit status by saying:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: with proper message"
    exit
fi
```

(There isn't any subshell involved here as far as I can see.)

Answer (score 0):

```
function try() {
  echo "$@"
  if ! "$@"
  then
    t="$_"
    echo "Failed, error $t"
    exit $t
  fi
  return $_ 
}

try mkdir /dev/sda # ;-)
```